# WebRTC. Not showing video

Tags: javascript, video, webrtc

I decided to study WebRTC, but not showing video. Help please.
What am I doing wrong? Using Chrome
My code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({ video: true }, getStream, noStream);
        };

        function getStream(stream) {
            var url = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);            
            var video = document.getElementById('video');
            video.src = url;
        }

        function noStream(faild) {

        }
    </script>
    <video id="video" autoplay="autoplay" width="400"></video>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with WebRTC.  In any case, I don't know if this is your problem but your code is dated.  Consider using the MediaDevices API, along with adapter.js to shim older browsers.  https://github.com/webrtc/adapter  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Comment: likewise https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/ shows an up-to-date example of using getUserMedia.

You might also want to consider adding logging to the error callback you call "noStream". There is a reason the argument you call "faild" is there, it helps figuring out what went wrong

Comment: @Brad thanks, it working

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Working code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var constraints = { audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } }; 

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then(function(mediaStream) {
  var video = document.querySelector('video');
  video.srcObject = mediaStream;
  video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
    video.play();
  };
})
.catch(function(err) { console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message); });
        };
    </script>
    <video id="video" autoplay="autoplay" width="400"></video>
</body>

</html>
```