# Stream live webcam barcode reader to HTML webpage(GUI)

Tags: python, html, opencv

I current have a python program for detecting barcodes and writes data to a text file.
How can I get the webcam barcode reader to run in a HTML webpage.

So far I have tried fiddling around with 2 options:

1. getusermedia:

By using getusermedia in html and using python eel to run the barcode detect function.(able to just open a webcam without detect function)

```
<script>
var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
    .then(function (stream) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
    })
    .catch(function (err0r) {
      console.log("Something went wrong!");
    });
}

</script>
```

2. Flask:

Using Flask to run, but I'm having error opening the webcam

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Video Streaming"""
    return_template('test.html')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(main(),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

While Flask seems to be more viable, I can't figure out how do I get it to run in HTML.

I'm not good with HTML(only knows the basic web design)

### Barcode reader Program

```
#import libraries
import datetime
import cv2
import time
import eel
from pyzbar import pyzbar

filename = datetime.datetime.now()
code=[]

def read_barcodes(frame):

    barcodes = pyzbar.decode(frame)
    for barcode in barcodes:
        x, y , w, h = barcode.rect
        #1 Decode barcode/Create frame
        barcode_info = barcode.data.decode('utf-8')
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y),(x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

        #2 Create text on top of the barcode
        cv2.putText(frame, barcode_info, (x + 6, y - 6), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (255, 0, 255), 2)
        #3 Update List 
        if barcode_info in code:
            print("Duplicate")
        else:
            code.append(barcode_info)
            print(code)
    return frame
@eel.expose
def main():
    #1 Open webcam using OpenCV
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)    #0(webcam) 1(camera)
    ret, frame = camera.read()
    #2 Loop till Esc is pressed

    while ret:
        ret, frame = camera.read()
        frame = read_barcodes(frame)
        cv2.imshow('Barcode/QR code reader', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
            break
    #Export to text
    with open(filename.strftime("%d %B %Y")+"barcode_result.txt", mode ='a+') as file:
        for x in code: 
            file.write("Recognized Barcode:" + x +"\n")
    #3 Close webcam
    camera.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
#4 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Check this answer on another question: [WebRTC. Not showing video](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41128167/11426731). This will make the webcam stream show up in the `video` element. You will need to create a `websocket` connection to your server to stream the data to your python code so that it can do it's magic.

Comment: Sorry this is quite new to me, how do I go about creating one, in python or Js?

Comment: Just search for tutorials about `websocket` servers in python. There should be plenty.